# Round variable in Javascript Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, variables, rounding

I am querying a Google Spreadsheet and the number I am getting is blowing up some weighting I am doing further down in the code.

My query:

```
function queryValue3(met1,met2,met3) {
var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B7:B9&key=my_key&gid=10');
query3.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query3: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data3 = response.getDataTable();

    var m1 = data3.getValue(0, 0);
    var m2 = data3.getValue(1, 0);
    var m3 = data3.getValue(2, 0);
```

The number I'm pulling for m2 is apparently 25.3333333333333323 and is blowing me up later in the function.  As long as my numbers are rounded to the 10th or 100th (in this case I want 10th) the function works fine.  I using the custom round (1 decimal) and it looks correct in the sheet but the query is grabbing the raw number?  In most cases my number is whole and I want it to not have a decimal in those instances.  Can someone help me modify the variable m1, m2, and m3 for this case?

Thanks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is `n.toFixed(2);`

You can use it to set the amount of numbers after the decimal.

Example:

```
foo = 25.3333333333;
foo = +foo.toFixed(2); 
// The plus makes it a number-type again, as toFixed converts to string.
console.log(foo); // 25.33
```

Edit: Decimal rounding occurs as an expected side-effect:

```
foo = 25.127;
foo = +foo.toFixed(2); 
console.log(foo); // 25.13
```

Whole numbers are left the same:

```
foo = 23;
foo = +foo.toFixed(2);
console.log(foo); // 23
```

Comment: Okay, this looks plausible.  Is there a way to say if its a whole number then leave to alone and if its a fractional number then apply toFixed?

Comment: You don't have to because `+5.toFixed(2)` leaves is alone already, producing `5`. If you leave out the '+' in front, then it produces the string `5.00`, but if you convert that to a number (like I did with '+') then you just get the whole-number again, '5'.